# freddo espresso pods vs espresso pods

Tags: espresso, espresso-machine

I'd like to consider myself a newbie at...coffee...consumption and I wanted to buy an espresso machine for myself and right now I'm between, a nespresso machine and a dolce gusto machine and the only thing that is holding me back is that, I can find freddo espresso pods for the dolce gusto machine but not for the nespresso one.

Now, I know that freddo means *cold*, but I don't know if there is a point in having different pods for freddo espresso and "normal" espresso.

That being said, does anyone know, in they're experience, if there is a difference between the two types of pods?

Answer (score -1):

One is coffee de-oiled and re-mixed, the other is instant coffee with added sugar, however only plastic pods instead of aluminum + plastic.

Comment: Uh... which one is which?

Comment: @Stephie points out something *very* important. Is it freddo espresso the pod that had the added sugar or the espresso one?